# Surface Integral

Tags: surface-integrals

Integrate $f=\frac{Y}{X}\sqrt{4Z^2 + 1}$ over the portion of the paraboloid $Z=X^2+Y^2$ that lies above the rectangle with the following limits:  $ 1\lt X\lt e , 0\lt y\lt 2 $ in the $X-Y$ plane."

I know that you use the formula, but i get stuck beyond that. Can someone show me a fully worked solution please on how to do this.

Many thanks

Please excuse the poor formatting. I don't know how to use this website properly just yet!

Comment: You are missing some information after "the following limits: 1". The first step is to paramtrize e surface. Do you know how to do that? (Hint: it's a graph already). Use the parametrization to form the surface area element. Then integrate.

Comment: Hmmm ok.  I will have a guess:   

 So do i sub one into the other? meaning Z=X^2+Y^2 into f(x,y,z)? and then continue to integrate over?

Comment: is that going in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, that is going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks.  So far i've got (after substitution ) f= y/x ( 4(x^2+y^2)^2+1)^0.5. Can you show me a worked solution please on how to go about finishing this Q?

Comment: Still no luck on this Q. Any one care to help ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have now progressed further and got to y/x((4(x^2+y^2)"+1)^0.5 (4x^2+4y^2+1)^0.5 dydx . This seems like an extremely complicated integral, have i done it correctly?

Comment: That looks right to me.  If you simplify the integrand it is not so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

We are asked to integrate the function
$$
f(x,y,z) = \frac{y}{x} \sqrt{4z^2 + 1}
$$
over the surface $S$ defined by
$$
S = \left\{(x,y,z)\mid 1 \leq x \leq e,\ 0 \leq y \leq 2,\ z = x^2 + y^2\right\}
$$

Stop to make sure you understand: the surface $S$ is two-dimensional.  If we are to integrate a function over $S$, it should break down to two variables.  Since, on $S$, $z=x^2+y^2$, we substitute it into the function $f(x,y,z)$.  So part of the integrand is $$f(x,y,z^2 + y^2) = \frac{y}{x}\sqrt{4x^2 + 4y^2+1}$$

Now remember the surface is not flat, but curved.  That curvature is accounted for in the integral by integrating against $dS$ instead of $dA$.  But since our surface is part of a graph, this is easy:
$$
dS = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2+1}\,dx\,dy
= \sqrt{(2x)^2 + (2y)^2 + 1}\,dx\,dy
$$
Putting this together, we have
$$
\begin{split}
    \iint_S f\,dS
        &= \int_1^e \int_0^2\frac{y}{x}\sqrt{4x^2 + 4y^2+1}\cdot \sqrt{(2x)^2 + (2y)^2 + 1}\,dx\,dy \\
        &= \int_1^e \int_0^2\frac{y}{x}\left(4x^2 + 4y^2+1\right)\,dy\,dx
\end{split}
$$

Hopefully you can proceed from here.  If not, reread your textbook's section on double and iterated integrals.